# Insert new element in an array

Tags: php

**EDITED**

```
$queryPremium ="Select * from tablename where premium = 1 order by id desc";
$rowPremium = mysql_query($queryPremium);

$queryNotPremium ="Select * from tablename where premium = 0 order by id desc";
$rowNotPremium = mysql_query($queryNotPremium);
```

now i want a single array where the order of the rowNotPremium will be maintained and $rowPremium will be inserted randomly after 2 data of $rowNotPremium or after 3data of $rowNotPremium...

How to do that?

Comment: Write your code here not only description.

Comment: I have to bring a magic ball to find what values your variables are holding

Comment: @Thamilan : best answer dude. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$newArray = $nonpremium + $premium
```

or

```
$newArray = array_merge($nonpremium, $premium)
```

Comment: This will not insert `$premium` in random positions.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You are right. The first version of the question was not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any bad practice here if you feel this can be edited please edit it...

```
<?php
$arr_a = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$arr_b = array('apples','oranges','bananas','peaches'); 

// How many elements are in the array we are inserting into
$count = count($arr_a);

// What was the last insert position? Make sure the next will be greater than this
$prev = 0;

// Loop through each of our elements to insert
foreach($arr_b as $value)
{
    // Generate a random value, higher than the previous
    // random number but still less than count($arr_a)
    $rand = rand($prev, $count);
    // Store this as the previous value + 1
    $prev = $rand + 1;
    // Insert our value into $arr_a at the random position
    array_splice($arr_a, $rand, 0, $value);
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($arr_a, true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**array_splice()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) and [**rand()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) functions

```
$array1 = array( 1,2,3,4,5 );
$array2 = array( 6,7,8,9 ); 
array_splice( $array1, rand(0,count($array2)-1), 0, $array2 ); // splice in at random position
```